# Arched UILabel in iOS

Tags: xcode, text, ios, uilabel, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to figure out a way to transform a UILabel so that the text is arched (hill shaped) but haven't had much luck. I've looked at CGAffine transforms but haven't found much on what I'm trying to accomplish. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check it's [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)?